# Angular kendo grid is not loading data on filter change event if current page do not have searched value

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a grid with a few pages. Let's say there is an item "Decaffe" on the first page, and I opened second page.
Then I apply filter, by using onFilter event, by typing word "Deacaffe" in separate search box outside of the grid. And grid became empty, no result was returned.
I'm attaching [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkdvup-ei3tla?file=src/app/app.component.ts) of it.
How to fix this issue? I assume additional refresh needed..

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <kendo-textbox (valueChange)="onFilter($event)"></kendo-textbox>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
        <kendo-grid 
          [filterable]="true" [filter]="filter" 
          [pageSize]="4" [pageable]="true"
          [kendoGridBinding]="gridData">
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID"> </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name"> </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category"> </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price"> </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor = {
    logic: 'and',
    filters: [
      {
        field: 'ProductName',
        operator: 'startswith',
        value: 'Chai',
        ignoreCase: true,
      },
    ],
  };

  public onFilter(inputValue: string): void {
    this.filter = {
      logic: 'or',
      filters: [
        {
          field: 'ProductName',
          operator: 'contains',
          value: inputValue,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  public gridData: Product[] = [
    {
      ProductID: 1,
      ProductName: 'Chai',
      UnitPrice: 18,
      Category: {
        CategoryID: 1,
        CategoryName: 'Beverages',
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found relatively easy solution by using DataBindingDirective with ViewChild directive, and calling skip method in the filtering event. In my case all grid is pre-loaded, otherwise you may load it with proper pagingation like in previous answer.. which would be more coding involved.
Working solution: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkdvup-hz8s2k).

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(DataBindingDirective) dataBinding: DataBindingDirective;

  public filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor = {
    logic: 'and',
    filters: [
      {
        field: 'ProductName',
        operator: 'startswith',
        value: '', 
        ignoreCase: true,
      },
    ],
  };

  public onFilter(inputValue: string): void {
    console.log(`onFilter - ${inputValue}`);

    if (inputValue) {
      this.filter = {
        logic: 'or',
        filters: [
          {
            field: 'ProductName',
            operator: 'contains',
            value: inputValue,
          },
        ],
      };
    } else {
      this.filter = {
        logic: 'or',
        filters: [],
      };
    }

    //the binding directive reference was used to set the skip property to 0. This is to ensure that the user will be returned to page 1 when filtering the Grid data.
    this.dataBinding.skip = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the workaround is you can apply your own [manual filtering](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/manual-filtering/) and [manual paging](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/paging/manual-paging/)

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkdvup-v7x2ee?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank you for your example. Looks like in it we substitute gridData with gridView, which is manually filterable & pageable.. It's a good amount of work, while I expected that grid will do this work for me. Hmm..